# New to code: Can I create a program to auto copy files from a shared drive onto desktop C:?

Tags: batch-file

I am unsure of how to go about doing this, but I would like to create a program using whatever is best to create a program to Copy and zip some files that are on a network drive and get them onto the desktop C:

I have no idea where to start other than I probably want a batch file of some sort. I am basically trying to make my service engineers jobs easier. The customer will be able to click on this program and it will auto copy all of the necessary programs, zip them, and then create a new zip file that they can send off for diagnosis.

Comment: You need to choose your compression software, decide on the options it requires and put together the command or sequence of processes in a batch file, if that's what you've chosen. Then try it. If it doesn't work as intended, add the code with a full explanation of what happened when you ran it, to your question by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50264033/edit).

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE].